# cannot telnet gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com 2195?

Tags: ios, linux, apple-push-notifications, telnet

On my server (Debian 3.2.54-2 x86_64 GNU/Linux), I use this command to check the connection with APNS (Apple Push Notification Server):

```
telnet gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com 2195
Trying 17.172.232.46...
Trying 17.172.232.45...
Trying 17.172.232.18...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection timed out
```

```
ping gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com
PING gateway.sandbox.push-apple.com.akadns.net (17.172.232.46) 56(84) bytes of data.
```

The telnet failed to help me connect. What is the reason for that?

1) Do I need to ask the admin to configure the firewall to let the telnet go through the port 2195?

2) When we use a telnet to a server with a given port, what port on our side will be open?

```
 telnet gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com 2195
```

means the port 2195 on APNS will be opened, so which port on our computer will be open to establish the connection?

Comment: have you found an answer?

Comment: i have the same problem; it seems the server at Apple is not responding gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com

Answer (score 0):

Use OpenSSL and pass a valid certificate, for testing purposes you can use  a self-signed certificate, for example, to create the pair `key` and `crt`:

```
$ openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -sha256 -nodes -keyout example.key -out example.crt -subj "/CN=example.com" -days 10
```

Then to create the `cert.pem`

```
$ cat example.key example.crt > cert.pem
```

Later you can test with:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195 -cert cert.pem
```

This will connect and do the handshake but you will get verification errors something like:

```
CONNECTED(00000006)
...
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
```

Comment: socket: Bad file descriptor
connect:errno=9